# How to set UIHostingController's background color to clear?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uihostingcontroller, zstack

I need to be able to see through my SwiftUI Views as well as the UIHosting Controller presenting them in order to see a background image underneath them.  The code below still shows a white rectangle under my SwiftUI View.  Paul Hudson [says](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/what-is-behind-the-main-swiftui-view) to use edgesIgnoringSafeArea but I cannot use that as my SwiftUIView is embedded in a larger UI scheme.  Is there any way to make this white rectangle I am seeing clear?

```
    var body: some View {
          ZStack {
            VStack {
                 //omitted
              }
        }.background(Color.clear)
   }
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are using a `UIHostingController`, you need to set the `backgroundColor` property of its `view` to `.clear` as well.

```
yourHostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: Note that the calling for push view must be made with:

view.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen //for transparency support
v.window?.rootViewController?.present(view, animated: true)